# Camera animation caused the camera disappeared

Tags: camera

I was working on a video in which camera moves along with the train object, all animation was going well. I am not sure what key I accidentally pressed and my camera is not showing in the view any more. Where as camera is still visible in the outliner.

How can I get my camera back?

Its easy to just delete the camera and create a new one but in this case I will lose my animation already applied on camera.

[image]

Comment: Please, add a screenshot, or upload a file

Comment: Is your camera on visible layer?

Comment: How may I check that ?

Comment: Select camera in outliner and find where is the yellow dot in the layers buttons

Comment: Wooww... I got it, so it was moved to a different layer, Thank you very much
Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Ok, and I added a information, interesting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you camera is not hidden and it is on visible layer.

And also you can try this:

> Its easy to just delete the camera and create a new one but in this
>   case I will lose my animation already applied on camera.

You will not lose animation because block with animation data will not delete with object.

So you can do this:

Open **dope sheet** in action editor mode

[image]

Find name of camera animation data:

[image]

When delete camera and create new one. And select animation data of your deleted camera:

[image]

Comment: Great, it make my day, Thank you very much :), Have a nice time.